# Advanced targeting like Facebook Sharings (Flexible ACL) DB Design

Tags: mysql, database, grouping, acl, rbac

I've been trying to develop an internal staff portal for our company. There are departments, job grades, working areas, roles (user, editor, admin, super admin, etc...) and special groups (executives, etc) for user grouping.

User must have one (only one) department.
User must have one (only one) job grades.
User must work in minimum one area.
User must have one (only one) roles.
User may have one or more special groups.

Job grades and roles are hierarchical (an grade or role may be inherited of another one) but other ones not.

Users will see only allowed menus and access permitted routes.

User will also select which users can view it when posting a new content.
e.g:
Combination 1: (IT or Finance department) and (Job Grade is one of 9,10,11) and (Area is one of 1,5,8) and (Exclusive special group is one of 1,5,8) except user id=1
Combination 2: (HR department) and (Job Grade is 11) and user_id=3,4,5

Combinations can be related as AND/OR among themselves like Combination 1 AND combination 2

So, there will be lots of contents and every content will have different group permissions. I try to create a DB schema but it's very hard to get all contents that is visible to logged in user. Serialized data would be good for saving combination sets in db but it looks like impossible with serialized data. Is there an advantage to using MongoDB for this issue? How can i save combinations of group/user permissions in tables also?

I researched lots of ACL and RBAC examples but can't find the optimal solution. Please help.

Btw, i use Laravel Framework.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex Righty System: ACL, RBAC and more what?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580702/complex-righty-system-acl-rbac-and-more-what)

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into attribute-based access control (ABAC - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-based_access_control)) and the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language (XACML). NIST, the National Institute of Science & Technology gives a great intro to [ABAC](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/) here.

XACML will give you the ability to express fine-grained access control policies that use you attributes. In your question you have:

- user attributes

  - department
  - job grade
  - working area
  - role
  - group
- object (resource) attributes

  - content type
  - content location
  - content classification

With XACML you can write rules such as:

> A user with grade==1 can do the action==edit on content of type==post
>   if content.department==user.department.

You can have as many rules as you like including conflicting rules or environment rules (deny access before 9am).

Have a look at the ALFA plugin for Eclipse to write your own policies ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML)) | [Download](http://www.axiomatics.com/alfa-plugin-for-eclipse.html)).

HTH,
David

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunetely no any PHP&MySQL implementation of ABAC. So, i can't imagine how to create DB schemas and write queries. :/

Comment: Have a look at PHP Slim and MySQL FGAC